# sed only works on one line

Tags: linux, bash, sed

For some reason, it's only performing the first line of sed in my script. The second line isn't being ran... to my knowledge. Did I forget something? I've been editing it for hours to no avail.

Script:

```
#!/bin/bash

#Locations
LocationOne="$SERVER_DIR/config.yml"

if [ -f "$LocationOne" ]
  then
    cd "$SERVER_DIR"
      sed -i "s/^.*\shost:.*/  host: $IP:$PORT/g" $SERVER_DIR/config.yml
      sed -i "s/^.*\sip_forward: false/  ip_forward: true/g" $SERVER_DIR/config.yml
fi
exit 0
```

config.yml:

```
listeners:
- query_port: XXXXX
  host: XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:XXXXX
timeout: 30000
connection_throttle: 4000
ip_forward: false
online_mode: true
```

First time posting, please be nice :) I'll edit as needed.

Comment: without sample data, we have to guess. My guess is that your 2nd `s/.../.../` isn't matching in the `s/.../` part, and so won't do a substitution. Also, you can put both subs into one call of sed, just separated with `;` (after you fix your main problem). (I didn't down vote, put please update your question with sample data that is failing, only 2-4 lines!) Good luck.

Comment: @shellter Thank you for being so kind. I added the stripped down config.yml, if that helps. It changes the host (first sed) but it doesn't seem to want to act on the ip_foward (second sed).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make the whitespace in front of the `ip_forward` optional, by adding a `*` after `\s`.

In your sample input, there is no whitespace character in front of `ip_forward`, so your expression doesn't match because it is requiring at least the whitespace character.

```
#!/bin/bash

#Locations
LocationOne="$SERVER_DIR/config.yml"

if [ -f "$LocationOne" ]
  then
    cd "$SERVER_DIR"
      sed -i "s/^.*\s*host:.*/  host: $IP:$PORT/g" $SERVER_DIR/config.yml
      sed -i "s/^.*\s*ip_forward: false/  ip_forward: true/g" $SERVER_DIR/config.yml
fi
```

On a separate note, you're matching `.*` in front of `ip_forward` which is any number of any characters (excluding newline), and I'm not sure if that was the intent.

Comment: Oops, I completely missed that... sed -i "s/ip_forward: false/ip_forward: true/g" $SERVER_DIR/config.yml

I don't know what I was thinking... Thanks for the help.

Comment: @RichardThai, The smallest things are the hardest to see.